# Is there a way to get the Saved Links?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get a user's Saved links?  These are the links that are accessible from the "Saved" URL on the left-hand side of your Facebook wall.

Thanks!

-JK

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/

You can do a

```
GET /v2.4/me/save.saves
```

to retrieve the saves.

Comment: It's not available now.

Comment: @allenlinli> Can you please share the SOI or how do i know if it is back?

Comment: @ProgramCpp what is SOI?

Comment: @ProgramCpp I just clicked on the link and it said it's not available.

Comment: Has anyone found the API for this?