# Facebook API returns empty videos list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

I'am trying to play with the opengraph facebook API. I'd like to fetch my videos by calling /me/videos

I'am using the Opengraph API explorer with a user access token but the response is always empty:  {data:[]}

My token is generated with every acces rights (I checked all checkboxes).

/me/photos is working fine, but not /me/videos

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Are you tagged on any videos?
By default, this endpoint only returns a list of videos that the person is tagged in. You need to specify to this endpoint if you're also looking for the video uploaded by you.

Comment: No, I'am not tagged in. These are videos I uploaded. To be more precise, I'd like to fetch videos I "saved". When I see a reciepe I like, I save it. And I retrieve them in the "saved" menu. I'd like to fetch them by API. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your comment I can tell your question doesn't describe what you're looking for. You're not looking for your uploaded/tagged videos, so this endpoint won't work for your case.

Just for information, this endpoint will only return a list of videos that the person is tagged in. You need to specify to this endpoint by adding a `type=uploaded` parameter to the query if you're also looking for the video uploaded by you.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

You're looking for your bookmarked links and it seems the API endpoint to access Facebook "Saved Links" is not available anymore ([Is there a way to get the Saved Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665727/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-saved-links))

Comment: Art, ok... Bad Luck 